# Ember view to display a PDF

Tags: pdf, ember.js

In one of my views I would like to display a PDF, which is accesible via URL. This should be done without opening an extra tab in the browser, and without downloading the PDF (to view it outside the browser). It should be visible embedded within the Ember application.

What I have in mind is:

1. Use the URL to get the PDF and make it accessible to the ember application.
2. Use a special "PDF view" to display the PDF.

Is this possible? What options do I have to display an embedded PDF in an Ember application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Displaying a PDF is not really related to ember, because to view a PDF you need a PDF plugin installed in your browser (which is mostly installed by default depending by the browser).

That said, a possible solution I could imagine could be to create a custom ember view with the tagName `iframe` on which you set the `src` attribute to the link referring to the PDF.

### Example:

```
App.PDFView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: 'iframe',
  attributeBindings: ['src', 'width', 'height', 'frameborder'],
  src: 'pdffile.pdf',
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  frameborder: 0
});
```

I've also used `width`, `height` and `frameborder` only for convenience so you can control some of the `iframe`'s attributes easily from within ember. Here a working [demo](http://jsbin.com/odosoy/83/edit).

You can also go with something more elaborated and use a js lib like http://pdfobject.com/ which you then initialize in your view's `didInsertElement` hook:

```
App.PDFView = Ember.View.extend({
  src: 'pdffile.pdf',
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  didInsertElement: function() {
    new PDFObject({ 
      url: this.get('src'),
      width: this.get('width'),
      height: this.get('height')}
    ).embed(this.get('elementId'));
  }
});
```

*(haven't tested the latter, but you get the point)*

And then use this `App.PDFView` like a normal ember view in your templates.

```
{{view App.PDFView}}
```

Or your can set the `src`, `width` & `height` directly from within your template like

```
{{view App.PDFView src="pdffile.pdf" width="600" height="800"}}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Both solutions are working very well. Not sure which one to use yet.

Comment: BTW, I haven't tried, but I guess the src in `{{view App.PDFView src="pdffile.pdf"}}` will not work in the second solution (no src property in the view?)

Comment: @gonvaled, sorry my bad, I simply forgot to add the attributeBindings like in the first example, I'll edit later my answer ...

Comment: Your ideas are working, but [here](http://jsbin.com/eKaWiYa/1/) an improvement suggestion, after playing around with it a bit. The attributes `width` and `size` are not valid html attributes (I think): they must be a part of the style. And `src` is already set in the PDFObject. Actually, width and height can be also set in the PDFObject.

Comment: @gonvaled, thanks for the suggestions? But `width` & `height` are valid attributes for the `iframe` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe however you are right in the case of a `div` there they should be part of the style declaration. As for PDFObject, I don't have worked with it so yes sure that they can be set on it. I'll update my answer to reflect this, thanks again.

Comment: great! Good for future reference for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly leverage the Ember PDFJS Addon by doing:

`ember install ember-pdfjs`

The [README](https://github.com/mysterlune/ember-pdfjs) on GitHub describes the installation and use cases.

In short, the addon provides your Ember project with a component, `pdf-document`, which you can use in your HTMLBars template like so:

`{{pdf-document src=[model.src]}}`

... there are other permutations of what `src` can be (including a string file path, resource URI, or `Uint8Array` buffer).

If you don't see a feature that you need, please suggest in the [Issues](https://github.com/mysterlune/ember-pdfjs/issues).